# Calibrate G-Sensor only for certain app

Tags: android, android-sensors

I want to ask you if is possible to calibrate Android Device Sensors (G-Sensor and Compass) by pressing a button. I am working on an application that uses magnetic sensors for pitch, roll and heading and the user must calibrate the sensors on every application start by touching a button.

Also if is possible to do so, is it able to save sensor configuration only for that application? Let's say you calibrate it from my app and after that you play a game. The settings must not be available for the game.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had 2 layers
1) GCa librationLayer
      for setting calibration point
2) GamePlayLayer
      where game is playing and we are using the value of sensor

so all you have to do is in game play layer when user press "calibrate it" button
run this code it will calibrating g sensor 50% above 0 point in Y axis (that we will see in GamePlay how)

```
void GCalibrateLayer::Calibrate()
{
    UserDefault *userdefault = UserDefault::getInstance();
    double calibrate_X = 0;
    double calibrate_Y = 0.5;
    userdefault->setDoubleForKey("callibrate_x",callibrate_X);
    userdefault->setDoubleForKey("callibrate_y",callibrate_Y);
}
```

in your gameplay first get this data in init() and save it variables "_calibrate_X" and "_calibrate_Y"

```
UserDefault *userdefault = UserDefault::getInstance();
_callibrate_X  = userdefault->getDoubleForKey("callibrate_x");
_callibrate_Y  = userdefault->getDoubleForKey("callibrate_y");
```

and in your onacceleration method
add values of these variables to accelerometer values and use new variables (_accelerometer_X,_accelerometer_Y) as acc->x and acc->y.

```
void GamePlayLayer::OnAcceleration(cocos2d::Acceleration *acc, cocos2d::Event *event)
{
    _accelerometer_X = acc->x +_calibrate_X;
    _accelerometer_Y = acc->y +_calibrate_Y;
}
```

You may use custom values that you get from accelerometer instead of 0.5 and 0 in GCalibrateLayer::Calibrate() too.

Hope you get the answer.